# Remove done button over keyboard in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, keyboard, editor, xamarin.forms.entry

I need to get text from user as input. I use editor because the input can be multiline. However when user focus the editor done button over keyboard is shown. I need to remove it. The done button does not show when I use entry instead of editor but i need to get input as multiline. Can I remove done button or can I use entry as multiline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a custom Editor Renderer for ios and remove done button successfully. Here is my code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEditor), typeof(CustomEditorRenderer))]
namespace ProjectName.iOS
{
    public class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            this.Control.InputAccessoryView = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The 'Done' button is default behavior. Check the documentation:
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/choose-keyboard-for-entry/

You can do some customizaton by working with the ImeOptions in a renderer: [Changing keyboard's ImeOptions of Xamarin.Forms.Entry in custom renderer not working on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690724/changing-keyboards-imeoptions-of-xamarin-forms-entry-in-custom-renderer-not-wor)